# When does the web3 object get injected into a webpage?

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I have a node.js app which was generated by the express generator. I want to use the web3 object injected by the Metamask plugin, but when I try to console.log(process.web3), it is undefined. When I type window.web3 into the browser's developer console, it returns the web3 object.

Does anybody know when the web3 object is injected and where in an express app I can assign something like

```
var web3 = process.web3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use web3.js server-side (inside Node.js), or client-side (inside a browser)? Looks like you're mixing these two cases up.

Client-side web3.js is initialized when the JS library is loaded by the browser. Usually, if you use something like [`$(document).ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) you'll be able to access it.

Server-side web3.js, though, requires [implicit initialization](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the following? I use this to connect to web3 injected by metamask.

```
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';

...

window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
        window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:8545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
        // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
        window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545"));
    }
});
```